# Grid Problem: Combining Item[] with SpanFromLeft/Above

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, grid-layouts, frame

I'm trying to lay-out a `Grid` with various entry-specific `Frame` settings.  In my case, using `Item[...,Frame->...]` just simplifies the code compared to using `Grid[...,Frame->{Automatic,Automatic,{{{a,b},{c,d}}->...}` with a long list of rules.

However, my grid includes some `SpanFromLeft` elements, too.  In a `Grid` containing *both* the noted `Item`s and `SpanFromLeft`s, it seems that only *some* options from `Item` are inherited by the `SpanFromLeft` cells.  For example, `Background` gets inherited, but `Frame` does not.

Does anyone know why this is, and whether it is a bug, and whether there are any workarounds other than the one I noted (as wanting to avoid)?

Here is an example:

```
Grid@{{Item[a, Frame -> All, Background -> Red], SpanFromLeft, 
   Item[b, Frame -> All, Background -> Red]}, {c, d, SpanFromAbove}}
```

Output:[image: Grid formatting with Item and SpanFromLeft]

Comment: looks like a version and/or os issue. Your code works as expected in version  13.1.0 (Linux x86  - 64-bit).

Comment: @kglr On your machine, could you evaluate `CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], {GridBoxOptions, GridBoxDividers}]` and give the result please ? Thanks

Comment: The result I get is  `{}`

Comment: OK. So it seems effectively to be version or OS dependent. On my machine (Window 7, Mma Version 12.2) I obtain the same result as the OP, with `CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], {GridBoxOptions, GridBoxDividers}]` returning `{}`.

Comment: I also get `{}`.  I'm running Mac OS X 13.2 with Mathematica 12.2.